# print out all elements of a list C++

Tags: c++, list

The following block of code is not working for me. The compiler says that for needs an argument.

the exact error message is Expected an Expression

```
alfa_it = alfa_list.begin();
cout << "the parties that are flying on Alfa are";
cout << for (alfa_it = alfa_list.begin(); alfa_it != alfa_list.end(); alfa_it++)
cout << " " << *alfa_it;
cout << endl;
```

p.s. alfa is intentionally misspelled.

Comment: List the full and exact text of errors please.

Answer (score 4):

You can't give `for` as an argument to `cout::operator<<`. You're probably looking for:

```
cout << "the parties that are flying on Alfa are";
for (alfa_it = alfa_list.begin(); alfa_it != alfa_list.end(); alfa_it++)
    cout << " " << *alfa_it;
cout << endl;
```